# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'parentOutlet.peekState')

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-nativescript

I have a multi-page angular-nativescript application (with a sidedrawer and a page-router-outlet). When I first launch the application I can navigate between pages on the sidedrawer just fine, but after a few minutes (like 10), trying to navigate from one page to another crashes the app with this message:

> JavaScript error:
>   file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:826:78:
>  JS ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'parentOutlet.peekState')
>   upsertModalOutlet@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.js:506:41
>   file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.js:128:44
>   forEach@[native code]
>   pushStateInternal@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.js:111:54
>   pushState@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.js:85:31
>   pushState@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-platform-location.js:49:40
>   pushState@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:511:45
>   go@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:286:45
>   setBrowserUrl@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4007:33
>   file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3960:40
>   file:///app/tns_m<\M-b\M^@\M-&>
>   *** JavaScript call stack:
>
>   (
>
>   0   UIApplicationMain@[native code]
>
>   1   start@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:272:26
>
>   2   run@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:300:10
>
>   3   bootstrapNativeScriptApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:185:26
>
>   4   bootstrapApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:103:38
>
>   5   bootstrapModule@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:87:26
>
>   6   anonymous@file:///app/main.js:7:57
>
>   7   evaluate@[native code]
>
>   8   moduleEvaluation@:1:11
>
>   9   promiseReactionJob@:1:11
>
>   )
>
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'parentOutlet.peekState')
>   upsertModalOutlet@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.js:506:41
>   file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.js:128:44
>   forEach@[native code]
>   pushStateInternal@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.js:111:54
>   pushState@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-location-strategy.js:85:31
>   pushState@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-platform-location.js:49:40
>   pushState@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:511:45
>   go@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:286:45
>   setBrowserUrl@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4007:33
>   file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3960:40

It's pretty reliably reproducible but I have to wait like 10 minutes each time

Comment: have you updated nativescript to the last version?

Comment: Yea, I'm on nativescript 5.1.0 and angular 6.1.0

Comment: looking in the source code, it seems like dialogs are the issue. Are you using these? Perhaps your implementation is wrong, and you are not closing them properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was related to how I was handling the routing between angular versions. In angular 4 I was using the `<router-outlet>` and had `tkMainContent` in a `<StackLayout>` that was surrounding it. When I switched to using `<page-router-outlet>` in angular 6 I needed to move the `tkMainContent` to inside the `<page-router-outlet>`

Comment: <page-router-outlet tkMainContent></page-router-outlet>
So this is not okay?

Comment: It's been a long time since I looked at this, but based on my answer I would think the syntax you said is fine

Comment: This is the configuration I have that is working: 

```<Page tkMainContent actionBarHidden="true" > enableSwipeBackNavigation="false">
    <page-router-outlet tkMainContent></page-router-outlet>  </Page>```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I found that it was caused because I used this in `main.ts` file:

```
platformNativeScriptDynamic({createFrameOnBootstrap: true}).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Changing this to:

```
platformNativeScriptDynamic({createFrameOnBootstrap: false}).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

or

```
platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

solved the problem.

This error particularly appeared while trying to load a Modal that uses the root view to show the modal.

According to the NativeScript documentation, you should use `createFrameOnBootstrap` in cases where your application does not use `page-router-outlet`, as without it you will not get the default `Page` and `Frame`, which means you will not be able to inject them in your components or show the `ActionBar`.

My application had `page-router-outlet`, so setting `createFrameOnBootstrap: false` solved this issue.